# comando SQL Creación de tabla

Tags: sql

Al poner este comando y darle ejecutar me dice:ORA-00907: falta una palabra clave.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (

NombreDelCliente VARCHAR(50)CONSTRAINT UK_CLI_NOM PRIMARY UNIQUE,

ApellidosDelCliente VARCHAR(50),

NIF VARCHAR(9) CONSTRAINT PK_CLI_NIF PRIMARY KEY, 

Sexo VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT CLI_SEX_CK CHECK (Sexo in ('M','H')),

DirecciónDelCliente VARCHAR(50),

Teléfono CHAR(9));
```

Comment: no se si es un error de tipeo, pero el nombre de las columnas no pueden llevar espacios

Comment: OK ya los quité. CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
NombreDelCliente VARCHAR(50)CONSTRAINT UK_CLI_NOM PRIMARY UNIQUE,
ApellidosDelCliente VARCHAR(50),
NIF VARCHAR(9) CONSTRAINT PK_CLI_NIF PRIMARY KEY, 
Sexo VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT CLI_SEX_CK CHECK (Sexo in ('M','H')),
DirecciónDelCliente VARCHAR(50),
Teléfono CHAR(9));   Pero me dice que falta una palabra clave

Comment: Tampoco pueden llevar tildes. Según el prefijo del código de error, parece que estás utilizando Oracle. Recomiendo leas acerca de las [reglas para nombrar objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223). También recomiendo leer [cómo crear tablas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503).

Comment: Gracias. Voy a ver ya quité tmbn las tildes

Answer (score 1):

La PRIMARY KEY deben ser única en la tabla. tú código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (    
NombreDelCliente VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT UK_CLI_NOM UNIQUE,
ApellidosDelCliente VARCHAR(50),
NIF VARCHAR(9) CONSTRAINT PK_CLI_NIF PRIMARY KEY,
Sexo VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT CLI_SEX_CK CHECK (Sexo in ('M','H')),
DirecciónDelCliente VARCHAR(50),
Teléfono CHAR(9));
```